# Linq to SQL select new pattern

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Is it possible to do one query to retrieve multiple database values with that pattern?

I have one view model call : FreemimumViewModel. Inside the view model I have:

```
public class FreemiumViewModel
{
    public FreemiumViewModel()
    {
        Skus = new HashSet<StockKeepingUnit>();
        Features = new HashSet<Feature>();
        RowValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        ColumnTitles = new List<string>();
        CanUsePromoCode = true;
        SelectionMatrix = new HashSet<FeatureStockKeepingUnitViewModel>();
    }

    public ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StockKeepingUnit> Skus { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FeatureStockKeepingUnitViewModel> SelectionMatrix { get; set; }
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public UserSubscriptionViewModel UserSubscriptionViewModel { get; set; }
    public bool CanUsePromoCode { get; set; }
    public string PromotionalCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// StockKeepingUnit name
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> ColumnTitles { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Key is the feature row title and object is the stock column value.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, object> RowValues { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to collect all database informations with that syntax :

```
 var vModel = (from skus in Context.Instance.StockKeepingUnits
                      from features in Context.Instance.Features
                      ...
                       select new FreemiumViewModel()
                       {
                           Skus = skus, // Need to be ICollection
                           Features = features // Need to be ICollection
                           ...
                       }).SingleOrDefault();
```

I try to do one request to database instead on multiple but I don't have my collections of skus and features. Can you help me?

Comment: For the collections in your viewmodel, it looks like you are attempting to load the entirety of each of the collections from the database, without any filters applied. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes it's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are trying to select the entirety of each collection into your viewmodel, you don't need a linq expression. You can just new up a viewmodel directly, ie:

```
   var viewmodel = new FreemiumViewModel
   {
        Skus = Context.Instance.StockKeepingUnits.ToList(),
        Features = Context.Instance.Features.ToList()
        ...
   };
```